# WooCommerce API: Create order with meta data on line item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using this API to create orders in WooCommerce: https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library

When I'm adding an order:

```
$orderData = array(
    "order" => array(
        "line_items" => array( 
            array(
                "product_id" => 1, 
                "quantity" => 1
            ) 
        )
    )
);

$client->orders->create($orderData);
```

everything works fine, the order is created in WooCommerce.

But When I want to add a product variation with meta data about the variation, how should I do that?

I tried several things, including:

```
$orderData = array(
    "order" => array(
        "line_items" => array( 
            array(
                "product_id" => 1, 
                "quantity" => 1,
                "variation_id" => 2,
                "variations" => array(
                    "color" => "black"
                )
            ) 
        )
    )
);

$client->orders->create($orderData);
```

What I want to achieve is, when getting the order with:

```
$client->orders->get( $order_id );
```

The color info is already added to the meta data of the line item (so the color description is visible in the order details when sending an email):

```
line_items: [
    {
        id: ...,
        subtotal: "...",
        subtotal_tax: "...",
        total: "...",
        total_tax: "...",
        price: "...",
        quantity: 1,
        tax_class: null,
        name: "Product name",
        product_id: 1,
        sku: "",
        meta: [
            {
                key: "color",
                label: "Color",
                value: "black"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Hope the question is clear enough and someone can point me to the right solution :)

Thanks for your patience to read this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify the product variation data when placing a order, the product variation should already exist and shall be referred to using the variation ID.

For example if you would place a order of the "black" variation (say it has variation ID 12):

```
"line_items": [
  {
    "product_id": 1,
    "variation_id": 12,
    "quantity": 1
  }
]
```

Adding metadata to a product variation can **not** be done using the `orders` endpoint, use the `products` endpoint for updating products.